# Let a,b be integers. Then $3 | a^2 + b^2$ if and only if 3 | a and 3 | b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove this using modular arithmetic but I'm a little stuck. Could I get some pointers? Thank you.

Let $a,b$ be integers. Then $3 | a^2 + b^2$ if and only if $3 | a$ and $3 | b$

Comment: Since a square can be only 0 or 1 mod 3 the result follows immediately.

Comment: There are only nine combinations of residue classes of $a$ and $b$. You can brute force this soon enough by testing them all. Symmetries will cut it down further very fast also.

Comment: Suppose $3\mid a$ and $3\mid b$.  Then that means that... which further means that... implying that $3\mid a^2+b^2$.  Now, suppose otherwise that $3\nmid a$ or $3\nmid b$.  Without loss of generality, suppose it was that $3\nmid a$.  Now, it follows that $a=3k\pm 1$ in which case $a^2=3(3k^2+6k)+1$... Continuing this implies... and further implies... which implies $3\nmid a^2+b^2$

Comment: I also warmly recommend that you study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: By modular arithmetic there are only three cases of what $a\mod 3$ can be and $3$ cases of what $b \mod 3$ can be so there are only $9$ cases of what $(a^2 + b^2)\mod 3$ can be.  If worst comes so worst just do them all and show $(a^2+b^2)\mod 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff a\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  But you can reduce this from $9$ steps to a lot fewer be making simple observations for example $x+y= y+x$ so if we test $a\mod 3\equiv x$ and $b\mod 3\equiv y$ we don't need to test $a\mod 3\equiv y$ and $b\mod 3\equiv x$.

Comment: However ... a very clever and powerful thing to so note is $a\equiv 2\pmod 3\implies a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $a\equiv 1\pmod 3\implies a^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ is *NEVER* possible.  So there are only $4$, not $9$ options for what $(a^2 + b^2)\mod 3$ can be.  You can have it be $0+0$ or $0+1$ or $1+0$ or $1+1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can show that $3|a, 3|b \implies 3|a^2+b^2$ fairly easily. For the other way, note that $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3 $ when $3$ doesn't divide $x$.

Comment: Congruence notation is $a\equiv b\pmod m$.  Meaning that $a-b$ is divisible by $m$. $b$ may be the remainder in integer division of $a$ by $m$, but it isn't constrained to be in the range $[0,m-1]$. OTOH the binary mod is reserved for denoting the remainder: `a\bmod m= r` yielding $a\bmod m =r$.

Comment: I think you meant "when $3$ doesn't divide $x$", not "when $x$ doesn't divide $3$"